# Add and save objects to parse.com db from django

Tags: python, django, parse-platform

I'm experimenting with parse.com as a db for my django app. I've installed parse_rest and am trying to follow http://runnable.com/UrzUjbmPNzlOAAOw/using-parse-com-with-python-for-tutorial-beginner-nosql-parsepy-saas-cloud-and-feedparser.

I have a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary of the form:

```
all_practices = {'a':value1, 'b':value2 ...}
```

I'd like to save this to parse.com. I have:

```
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object
    practices = Object()
    for p in all_practices:
        practices = p
        practices.save()
```

This is giving me:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'save'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using ParsePy.  If you don't want to write your own wrapper for parse.com (which I suggest), try calling "register" first.  Then define a python class that inherits from the Object

```
from parse_rest.connection import register
register(<application_id>, <rest_api_key>)



from parse_rest.datatypes import Object
class Profile(Object):
    pass




# instantiate with parameters
profile = Profile(name='Johnny', age=27)

# Change parameters
profile.name = "John"
profile.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. 2 questions though: 1) Do you have to call register every time you instantiate an object 2) I'm new to python so by "class Profile(Object): pass" , I think what you are doing is creating an object with parameters to be defined later?

Comment: @user61629 1) If you haven't done registered in that script, but you don't have to do it for every instantiation.  2) In this case, yes.  You would have the object parameters there, but django also has awesome types of views called class based views that allow for built-in and custom methods.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/