# Can a dictionary be passed directly to instantiate another object in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm experimenting with parse.com as a db for my django app. I've installed parse_rest.

I have a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary of the form:

```
all_practices = {'a':value1, 'b':value2 ...}
```

according to the answer provided by Michael Otte, in [Add and save objects to parse.com db from django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900946/add-and-save-objects-to-parse-com-db-from-django)

I can save this object by the following:

```
from parse_rest.datatypes import Object
class Profile(Object):
    pass

# instantiate with parameters
profile = Profile(name='Johnny', age=27)
```

is there a way to directly pass dictionary object as the parameters of the profile object, so as to get:

```
profile = Profile(a='value1', b='value2')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use the [keyword/dictionary unpacking operator `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
profile = Profile(**all_practices)
```

Comment: Basically this is how to use *args & **kwargs - there are tons of references to the concept, for more complete description of how it works google those terms.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it easy! - Bill